# Cordova whitelist iOS 10 SSL error: Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made

Tags: ios, cordova, vimeo, whitelist

I am trying to send an ArrayBuffer to

```
https://1511921174.cloud.vimeo.com/upload?ticket_id=xxxxxxxxxx&video_file_id=xxxxxx&signature=xxxxxxxx=1%22
```

In iOS 10 nothing is happening. There must me a whitelisting error. I am whitelisting *.vimeo.com and *.cloud.vimeo.com per the cordova-plugin-whitelist docs. Everything works fine in iOS 9 and on Android.

```
<access origin="http://*.vimeo.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="https://*.vimeo.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="http://*.cloud.vimeo.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="https://*.cloud.vimeo.com" subdomains="true" />
```

Any ideas what could be happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this isn't a whitelist but an App Transport Security issue.

I got the videos to upload to Vimeo using iOS 10. It looks like there may be a problem with Vimeo's SSL certificate. They may use an old TLS version. When I turned off the App Transport Security in the plist it just worked:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

So without turning everything off I ended up adding the code below in the plist for vimeo.com only:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>vimeo.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I hope that helps anyone out there.

Comment: Only thing that got it working for me...I can swear I put this in before but it obviously didn't save...I think I had to edit the plist file directly using a text editor and not xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make tweaks to the Content-Security-Policy meta tag for iOS 10 ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410159/cordova-app-hanging-during-startup-on-ios-10-beta)) so it's possible that you also need to add/update that, e.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' gap: file: https://*.cloud.vimeo.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data:; media-src *">
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added your code to my CSP but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Before I was adding Info.Plist entries with the edit-config tag in config.xml.
But for an obscure reason it wasn't working when I was overriding the NsAppTransportSecurity entry.

After some research, I  that the cordova-plugin-whitelist is also translating the "access" and "allow-navigation" tags in the config.xml to a NsAppTransportSecurity entry in the Info.Plist file since october 2015 ([source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9569)).

So the plugin was blocking my edit-config tag in my config.xml from overwriting this entry.
According to [this doc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/#ios-whitelisting) from Cordova, you can set the transport security options in the "access" and "allow-navigation" tags in config.xml.
I did this and now it works great.