# Ajax call fails on iOS 10 but works fine on previous versions for Cordova application

Tags: ajax, cordova, ios10

I am using the latest iOS platform and plugins in my cordova application. The app works fine on older versions of iOS but not on iOS 10. I am getting timeout error. Tried removing platform and adding again. Also created a fresh project. Still no luck. The app works fine on Android as well.

Comment: Possibly a whitelisting issue - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39501523/777265) for potential solutions

Comment: Did try that. Still not working. The same application pointing to webservice on staging environment works (on iOS 10 too) but when pointing to production APIs, they do not work on iOS 10 but works on older version. Really strange issue. :(

Comment: @NikitaAhluwalia Could be a possible Transport security issue. Try using this pugin - https://github.com/robertklein/cordova-ios-security

Comment: Nope! Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same Problem and apparently there is no fix at this time. Here is the current thread with this bug in the apple forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64526

Answer (score -2):

This is a similar issue to this one : [Cordova whitelist iOS 10 SSL error: Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501523/cordova-whitelist-ios-10-ssl-error-failed-to-load-resource-an-ssl-error-has-oc)

I found that it solved my problem with API calls and WebViews that broke when iOS 10 came out.