# Ionic 1 app XHR request working on Browser/Android failing on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a `POST` request to an external API using `fetch`.

On `iOS 10` I don't receive any reply, no errors and I can't see any network activity related to my request in safari's web inspector.

I've the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` installed and `<access origin="*"/>` in my `config.xml`. I've also added an `access-origin` rule with the URL of the API, without success.

**EDIT:** seems like iOS webview doesn't have `fetch`, I installed a polyfill and now I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

Adding `<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>` to my `info.plist` doesn't solves it.

Any tip or help on how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: add follwoing meta tag in index.html with replace your service api address in above meta tag **<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data:; default-src * gap://ready file: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  https://yourdomain.com; style-src  http: https: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http: https: ;" />**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have this at the moment `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * ; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * blob:; img-src * data:; font-src * data:">`  I have probably made some progresses, seems like iOS doesn't have `fetch`

Comment: please replace with my give one, but please change **yourdomain.com** with you service IP address

Comment: Done, but it does no difference :( I've updated my question

Comment: for ssl try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501523/cordova-whitelist-ios-10-ssl-error-failed-to-load-resource-an-ssl-error-has-oc or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755674/ios9-getting-error-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the-ser or https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing my URL is `my.api.domain.com` adding

`<access origin="https://*.api.domain.com/" />`

to my config.xml solved my issue