# Why is app not working after update to xcode8? (cordova)

Tags: ios, xcode8

My app works fine, but since I updated xcode there appears several problems. Now I get following error:

[image: xcode 8 log]

It's also interesting that the first request works pretty good and after that successful request the next request "crashes" the app.

environment:

- cordova 5.3.3
- xcode 8
- ios 10
- osx 10.11.6

Thanks for any suggestions!!!

Comment: Xcode 8 has extra logging enabled by default, I think it's been filed as a bug, this isn't quite an error. its just logging network related information. If you are having a specific problem with your app please provide more information on the code you have, what error your getting or what unexpected behaviour your having, including what it should do

Comment: your system os version?

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya 10.11.6

Comment: @Scriptable as I mentioned in the question, I get no error but the behavior ist different. At one point the app gets stuck at the second https call.

Comment: your network requests should handle both successful and failed network responses and display or log the relevant information. from the info provided above I am not able to tell you what the problem is.. please show the code that runs when the app initiates, how you make the network requests and handle them

Comment: I get the same error. The app is not able to connect to the internet. Safari on the simulator works but the app built on Xcode8 is unable to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38410379 :
It seems that iOS 10 requires additional entries in the Content-Security-Policy meta tag, namely gap://ready and file:. After adding these, my Content-Security-Policy looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Comment: No sry, this isn't working but I think it's the right way, because I tried to remove this line and the app works fine with ios 10