# Phonegap on iOs 10. Not displaying navigator.notification.alert

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

[image]

I have a button that gets pressed to log in. If your username or password not typed in it gives a notification.alert requesting information.

On iOs 10, it does not display while the page on the front. if I press the home button twice and the app goes to the background, the alert appears on the app?
Any Help

Answer (score 3):

This sounds similar to the symptoms described by [Chis Rae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498949/chris-rae) in his comment on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38410379/777265) to [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38410159/777265).

Try adding the `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag and see if it fixes the issue:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```