# Ionic app freezes on first iOS launch after XCode 8.1 update

Tags: ionic-framework, xcode8, visual-studio-cordova, taco

After updating to XCode 8.1. Ran into the same problems compiling as defined [here](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#xcode8). After implementing each of these steps I was able to build both of my apps again however now when I try to load either of them via Simulator or on a Device through Hockey app. They both freeze on the first screen and become unresponsive. Looking for an answer or steps to debug this problem.

Comment: Same issue, do you find sollution for it?

Comment: Hope this helps..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962799/cordova-6-3-1-on-ios-10-and-xcode-8?newreg=0e0d63763c3e4eeba0976a56086de096

Comment: Did you get any log from Hockey App?