# Cordova freezes on loading page, Cordova 4.2.1, iOS 10.0

Tags: ios, cordova

I have been developing with cordova for a while and never seen this before, which is my app hangs during loading of the first page. If I press home button and then click on my app or swipe up or down, the account page can be successfully loaded. Here is the link [(http://pan.baidu.com/s/1pLU2txp)](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1pLU2txp) to one downsized project which shares the same problem. Thanks a lot in advance for your concern and help...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38410379/777265 - specifically, see the comment by @Chis Rae

Comment: @DaveAlden Thanks!!! That did save a tremendous amount of time for me....

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the problem and the solution thanks to this post:

It seems that iOS 10 requires additional entries in the Content-Security-Policy meta tag, namely `gap://ready` and `file:.` After adding these, my Content-`Security-Policy` looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

And the app starts up and works fine on iOS 10.

Hope this helps others.