# PhoneGap "Hello World" app stuck on "Connecting to device"

Tags: cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

### Background Info & Problem

I downloaded the PhoneGap Desktop App for OSX, following the instructions here: http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/desktop/

I installed the PhoneGap app for iOS.

I've ensured both my laptop and iPhone are on the same network (no firewall).

I created a new "Hello World" project, using the PhoneGap Desktop App.

I was able to run the application via the desktop app– and then successfully connected to the web server, using the iOS app.

However, it appears the deviceready function is not firing-- the "Hello World" app is stuck in a perpetual state of `Connecting to device`. It never says `Device is ready`.

### Additional notes...

I've tried solving this issue by following the guidance from this post: [Cordova app hanging during startup on iOS 10 (beta)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410159/cordova-app-hanging-during-startup-on-ios-10-beta)

If I tap the home button on my iPhone, and then re-enter the PhoneGap app, it says `Device is ready`.

I'm running OSX 10.10 and iOS 10.0.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have the exact same issue going on now, did you happen to figure it out?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. The phonegap skeleton app gets stuck on 'connecting to device'... Did you solve the problem? thanks in advance for sharing the solution.

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410159/cordova-app-hanging-during-startup-on-ios-10-beta?noredirect=1&lq=1) solved for my case.

Answer (score 1):

in the terminal type in "sudo npm install ios-sim -g"
References:
https://disqus.com/home/discussion/jetbrains/using_phonegapcordova/