# Ionic Cordova camera issue with ios 10

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

I am using ionic 1 with cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.0.
I am using latest version of cordova.

When I press button to get image whether to use camera or gallery ($cordovaCamera.getPicture) in ios 10, nothing happens. If I press home button and go back into the app, camera or gallery pops up right away.

I have already enabled the permission for it.

This is working perfect for ios 9 and below and all android versions.

Please help.

Comment: did you add **NSCameraUsageDescription** in info.plist file?

Comment: Yes I installed the plugin with cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --variable CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="We requires access to your camera" --save

Comment: I found the answer to this issue probably here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410159/cordova-app-hanging-during-startup-on-ios-10-beta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirm this is solved in [Cordova app hanging during startup on iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410159/cordova-app-hanging-during-startup-on-ios-10-beta) as Sven Sönnichsen indicated in the comment to the question.

Add `gap://ready file:` to the Content-Security-Policy meta tag in `index.html`.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; script-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos; *; style-src  &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; *">
```

This was also addressed here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2211591 where Allsetra ICT said that changing the meta tag to this simple form also worked (although I did not verified it).

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: sorry but "in config.xml" ?? isn't that into index.html?

Comment: @BraianMellor Thank you. I edited my answer to reflect that the file that needed to be changed is index.html

Comment: I am getting the result as a base64 image and for that I had to modify the configuration a little. This is the relevant part: `img-src 'self' data: *; default-src * gap://ready file:;...`