# PhoneGap Build 6.3.0 geolocation getCurrentPosition slow on IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation, ios10

I am new in developing on PhoneGap Build. While testing some basic app functionalities I experience a timeout problem when doing a simple geolocation request on my Iphone 6 / IOS 10 / PhoneGap Build 6.3.0.

After re-installing the app I start it and initiate the geolocation by onclick -> geolocation().

Only when I turn the app to the background, I receive the IOS request to allow the location request (should come when I first do the onclick -> geolocation while having the app in the foreground).

Sometimes I get a geolocation result after a long time, sometimes not. I've tried all possible combinations on the three PositionOptions.

When I ask the Google Maps app it shows me the location immediately.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you, Kim

```js
function do_geolocation(){
 alert('do geoloc');
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_onSuccess, geo_onError, {maximumAge:120000, enableHighAccuracy:false} );

}
onclick=do_geolocation();



function geo_onSuccess(position){

 alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');

 var arr = new Array();
 arr['lat'] = position.coords.latitude;
 arr['lng'] = position.coords.longitude;

 var x = new Date();var cb = x.getTime();
 

}
function geo_onError(position){
 
  alert('code: '+error.code+'\nmessage: '+error.message+'\n');
 return false;

}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "de.vvvvvv.secapp"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "1.0.0" >

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

  <name>vvvvvvv</name>

  <description>
      vvvvvvvvvvvv
  </description>

  <author href="http://vvvvvvv.de" email="info@vvvvvv.de">
      Kim
  </author>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.1" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1" />
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>


<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />

<!-- https://makeappicon.com/ios10icon -->
<icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon-App-20x20@2x.png" platform="ios" width="20" height="20" />
<icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon-App-20x20@3x.png" platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only when I turn the app to the background, I receive the IOS request to allow the location request (should come when I first do the onclick -> geolocation while having the app in the foreground).

The activation only on backgrounding the app sounds sympomatic of a `Content-Security-Policy` issue ([here's another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859236/my-app-only-work-in-background-ios-10/40884685#40884685)).

To resolve, ensure that your `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag contains `gap://ready` and `file:` entries for `default-src`. For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

> Sometimes I get a geolocation result after a long time, sometimes not. I've tried all possible combinations on the three PositionOptions.

Setting `maximumAge` to `120000` means a position up to 2 minutes old (cached by the OS) can be used. To force a fresh position, set it to zero:

```
{
    enableHighAccuracy: false
    maximumAge: 0,
    timeout: 2000
}
```

If setting `enableHighAccuracy` to true, this engages GPS hardware to get a lock, so set a sufficient timeout to allow it to lock enough satellites:

```
{
    enableHighAccuracy: true
    maximumAge: 0,
    timeout: 30000
}
```

For a full explanation of PositionOptions, see the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions)

Comment: Hello Dave, thanks a lot for your detailed advice! I did't recognize your quick answer. I've changed the Content-Security-Policy as suggested and it's working now. Will now take a closer view into the security policy setup options.