# Phonegap Iframe IOS 10 not loading but working on android

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe

I have a simple phonegap app that only have iframe that load external url, but the iframe is not loading. it's blank

i have searched and tried every other possible solution lke whitelisting the url

my config.xml contains this:

```
<access origin="*" /> 
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```

and the loaded url contains this csp:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

does anybody have an idea about this?

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38410379/777265): add `gap:` and `file` protocols to your default-src

Comment: thanks, solved the problem