# Cordova iOS WebView loses touch events, interface is unresponsive

Tags: ios, cordova, click, touch

I developed an app with Framework7 with material theme + Cordova cli 6.5.0 and Cordova-iOS 4.3.1 and Xcode 8.3. Sometimes, the app loses touch events. The interface doesn't work, but the app is working because onresume Cordova event, I call a function that showes a message and it appears. But touch events don't work, the interface is unresponsive. Sometimes, after some minutes, the interface returns responsive, otherwise the only solution is reopening the app. Has anyone seen this issue? Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Thats why I ❤ Cordova ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38410159/777265