# Cordova/iOS - All notification dialogs are behind app

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

With iOS 10/11, everything is behind my app. From simple notification dialogs to the contacts list when I try to open the contacts. Also, I amnot prompt to allow permissions for contacts until I trigger the plugin. Is there a way to prompt the user at initial app launch for permissions to Contacts as well as Push Notifications? (Using OneSignal)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

All plugins and cordova versions are the latest.

Comment: How do you know they are behind your app?

Comment: Well, I guess I don't but they don't show up until I double tap the home button. For example, when I tap the button to open the navigator.contacts.pickContact, it doesn't show up until I double tap the home button to open the app switcher, then the pickContact menu/window slides up from the bottom. As for navigator.notifications.alert, same thing. They don't show up until I double tap the home button. Oh, and the same goes for the request permissions to access contacts and receive push notifications.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38410159/777265