# Camera/Photo gallery runs in background with Cordova plugins in IOS Devices

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, sapui5, phonegap

I'm using cordova plugins in UI5 app to use camera/photo gallery and barcode scanner phonegap plugin. When I made a IOS build through XCode and installed the app on iPad, Camera doesn't open on first click instead if I minimize the app by pressing home button and again open the app, camera will be opened. It happens with photo gallery/ barcode scanner plugins as well. App has the required permissions to access camera. Please give inputs if any of you have encountered this issue. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38410159/777265

Comment: Thanks @DaveAlden. I have already fixed this issue. I have removed the security tag which you mentioned in my index.html as this was causing issues as I was using app for IOS 11.1 version.