# Cordova iOS plugin doesn't work until the app changes focus

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using this plugin https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-touch-id on my app. When I call the methods, the callbacks are not called until I focus out the app and bring it back in focus. I have seen this same problem with two different plugins. Is this a cordova ios bug or is there some thing that I need to do?

```
window.plugins.touchid.isAvailable(
  function(type) {alert(type)}, // this will not be called until I focus out and back in the app
  function(msg) {alert('not available, message: ' + msg)} // this will not be called until I focus out and back in the app
);
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you compiling the app for Android as well and this is not happening there?

Comment: See [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38410159/777265) - pretty sure this is your problem

Comment: @DaveAlden the question is the same, the answer not quite as he posted his CSP on cordova slack and he has the `gap:` on `default-src` already. The problem is he also has a `frame-src` entry. In that case the `gap:` should go there instead of on the `default-src` as `gap:` is used in an iframe. Maybe it's something you can add to your answer to improve it.

Comment: Right @DaveAlden  @jcesarmobile I had the ```frame-src``` and added the ```gap:``` there and it worked. Thank you!