# Ionic 3 Ios plugins not working until app gets in background

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ios-camera

I'm building a cross platform app using Ionic 3.19.1,

On Android everything runs fine, but when i build the app for IOS and then run it on a device using Xcode i get some unexpected behaviour:

Expected:

1) Clicking on a button, the dialer should open and make a call

2) Clicking on a button, the camera should open

Actual:

None of those actions happen until the app gets into background, for example when opening the notifications bar or the tools bar on the bottom.

CODE:

This is the code used for making a phone call, using @ionic-native/call-number

```
this.callNumber.callNumber("+123456789", true)
.then(() => this.navCtrl.setRoot(CompletedPage))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

This is the code used to open the camera, using @ionic-native/camera

```
  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 60,
    targetHeight: 600,
    targetWidth: 600,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
  }

  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

  }
```

The code and cordova plugins are correctly set up and working fine, the only problem is that they don't get executed until some event occurs on the page (i guess focus event or something related),
i'm not getting errors for the call-number, but i'm getting a warning for the camera:

```
Attempt to present <CDVCameraPicker: 0x17a84e00> on <MainViewController: 0x176345a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I looked around for that message but i couldn't fine nothing related to ionic.

Any kind of help or just link to resources will be appreciated!

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38410159/777265) for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks @DaveAlden ! That worked great